# Kubernetes - how to mount existing persistent volume locally

Tags: debugging, localhost, kubectl, mount

When I work with AWS, I can create storage volumes and bind them in kubernetes.
I would like to mount the persistent volume locally, in order to inspect the volume content and manipulate files with a local script.
**Is there a handy way to mount a persistent volume to the client host, with something like**: `kubectl niceMountCommand my-pvc /data/local/my-pvc`
I already know about `kubectl cp` and the possibility to add a dummy pod to access data, but I would have to adapt every script that manipulates data to exec commands through `kubectl exec`.